# SharePoint 2010 list view style

Tags: list, listview, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

In SharePoint 2010 for XSLT List View Web Part you can assign different styles using SharePoint Designer. For example "Basic Table", "Boxed" or "Shaded" etc. These styles just don't fit my needs. So my question is how can I create my own View Style which I can apply to any list?

I came across "Customize XSLT > Customize Entire View" option under Design tab in SharePoint Designer which allows me to change the XSL stylesheet and control the rendering for a list. But how can I create my own list "View Style" which I would like to reuse with other lists too?

Thanks
Hitesh